# Cloudflare KV namespace not defined from `wrangler dev`

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-kv

I've read all the docs and SO posts I can find, but I'm still getting a "sonarkv is not defined" when running my worker locally with `wrangler dev`. Here what I've done:

- Created a preview namespace:

`$ wrangler kv:namespace create "sonarkv" --preview`

- Added it to wrangler.toml:

```
kv_namespaces = [
    { binding = "sonarkv", id = "5138eb663ac04eb6af5fe72d11966626", preview_id = "67e98d40e1e74329bf2c30dd92289fce" }
]
```

- Verified it:

`$ wrangler kv:key list --binding sonarkv --preview`

```
[
  {
    "name": "somekey"
  }
]
```

`$ wrangler kv:key get somekey --binding sonarkv --preview`

```
<...correct value...>
```

- And referenced it in my worker script:

```
    const secret = await sonarkv.get("somekey");
```

- Wrangler version:

```
$ wrangler --version
 ⛅️ wrangler 3.9.0
------------------
```

What am I missing here? Do I need to bind the preview namespace separately in the dashboard? (When I try it fails with "A variable with that name already exists".)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Despite this not being documented anywhere that I can find, you now need to pull the namespace binding from the `env` parameter that's optionally given in `fetch()`. So:

```
export default {
    async fetch(request, env) {
    ...
    const secret = await env.sonarkv.get("somekey");
    ...
}
```